# Do I have to change param's type when migrating my lib to 64bit?

Tags: c, 64-bit

I am migrating my lib from 32bit to 64bit. The library is written in C. Say for the following API:

```
void foo(uint32 var)
```

Do I have to change the type of var to `uint64` in any circumstances? What if max of var is not greater than `0xffffffff`?

Comment: No, generally not. When you write `uint32` you're saying that you only need 32 bits for that data. You *could* change it to `uint64` if you wanted to handle larger numbers, but then you'll have to find all the callers and change them as well.

Comment: Thanks. What you said is if ```uint32``` is big enough, don't change, unless the variable exceeds the limit of ```uint32``` in 64-bit environment. Right?

Comment: The answer depends on the meaning of the function and the parameter, obviously . There's no generic answer for foo  . Any function can have a 32-bit int argument or a 64-bit argument, regardless of the bits of the library (whatever that even means) .

Comment: In general, upgrading to 64-bit is mainly about the sizes of default types increasing, like pointers, file sizes. Anything you give explicit size to normally stays the same.

Comment: Development of 64-bit C and C++ applications: https://www.viva64.com/en/l/full/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have to change the type of var to `uint64` in any circumstances? What if max of var is not greater than `0xffffffff`?

Nothing says you have to change your datatypes when compiling for 64-bit. The `uint32` parameter will behave the same as it did before. (However, you should probably be using `uint32_t` from `<stdint.h>` if you want to guarantee that your data types work correctly.)

There are a few other places where you *want*
 the size of your variables to change, but the behavior will be automatically correct if you use the correct data types:

- `uintptr_t` This is a pointer-sized integer. So you can cast from `void*` to `uintptr_t` and back without losing any information. If you instead cast from `void*` to `uint32_t`, you will corrupt your pointers.
- `off_t` The size of file offsets might change (depending on your toolchain), so you should use this appropriate typedef.